# Making User Wait for 30 Seconds in Compact Framework

Tags: multithreading, compact-framework

I have a application in which i am sending a SMS to the Server which will return the result as an SMS. So i have put a Message Intercepter with the Event Handler. The Problem is that Once i send the request i have to wait for 30 seconds before i go ahead with the operation. How do i make my application wait till that. if i use the Thread.sleep it is making the whole application sleep and i am not getting any response out there.

Any idea how to tackle this

Thanks in Advance
Regards
Biju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I assume you are trying to do is prevent the user from advancing until they receive a valid response from SMS, as some kind of authentication with a timeout of 30 seconds if the response was not received.

To do this, you could display a modal dialog that just displays the "Waiting for SMS Response.." message and close the dialog once 30 seconds have elapsed (using a Timer) or a response is received from SMS.

Comment: THanks Skeeve. This is working now. I have put a Modal Window which waits for 30 Seconds. Thanks for it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could use a timer of some kind. If you need to execute your code within the UI thread, you could use a [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx); if you're happy with it executing in a thread pool thread you could use [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) or [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx).

I don't know offhand which of these are available in the Compact Framework, but I'd expect at least one of them to be.

If they're really not available, one option which is kinda hacky but would work is to create a new thread which just sleeps for 30 seconds and then either executes the code you need or marshals to the UI thread (using Control.Invoke/BeginInvoke) to execute there if necessary. It's about as crude a timer as you can get, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I can't use either the Timer and the Thread. if i use the thread as Thread.Sleep(30000). it is making the Application to sleep till 30 seconds and it is getting live after 30 seconds and i am not able to capture the return sms as my application will go for the next process. Any other Solution where the SMS Intercepter would be running the background but the user will be forced to wait till 30 seconds.

Comment: @Biju: No, you've misunderstood me - I didn't say to call Thread.Sleep *within the UI thread* - you'd create a *new* thread which performed the sleep. If you want to stop the user from doing anything else, then disable the controls which would let them create a new SMS (or whatever it is you want to prohibit). Oh, and you haven't said *why* you can't use Timer. Could you give more details?

Answer (score 0):

The event should fire asynchronously, so your program continues. You can have the event handler set a flag to continue on whatever path your program is taking.

also, as a side note, if you ever find yourself thinking "gee, `Thread.Sleep(1000)` would work great here" take a step back and examine the situation. Most of the time, you can do it asynchronously with events.

Comment: Thanks Scott. let me give you the exact Picture:                             splashScreen.DisplayText("Sending SMS");
SMS.SendMessage("xxxxxxxxx", "GR " + GlobalCache.Instance.EmployeeCode);
splashScreen.DisplayText("Waiting for SMS Response..."); Thread.Sleep(30000). I have put this plus the Event Handler for the SMS interceptor. The Intercepter is waiting till the Thread.Sleep completes.  Flow continues as the application is not able to receive the reply from the server.